# Windows defender Obfuscating Batch script Command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-defender

I was creating a simple  batch script file that adds an exclusion to windows defenfer for my convenience. 
The code I use is as follows:

```
@echo off
echo test for exclusion
powershell.exe Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath “C:\Temp”
cmd /k
```

However, when I execute it, *(even with admin privelleges)*, - the excluded file path in windows defender shows up as some obfuscated nonsense:

[Window Defender Ofbuscating File path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZJwz.png)

Comment: Why are you using `smart`/`curly` quotes insteas of `dumb`/`straight` quotes? `"C:\Temp"` or `'C:\Temp'`

Comment: Thank you stranger!!!! I changed it to single quotes and it works fine, a silly mistake on my part  I guess!

Comment: There's nothing strange about me, that's why they released me!